# Installing a Windows Service with dependencies

Tags: .net, windows, windows-services, .net-2.0, installation

My installer program doesn't suppport installing services but I can run a program/command line etc so my question is how can I install a Windows Service and add 2 dependencies using the command line? The program is a .Net 2.0 app.

Thanks

Comment: What install system are you using?

Answer (score 17):

You can write a self-installing service and have it set a list of services your service depends on when the installer is executed.

Basic steps:

- Add a reference to System.Configuration.Install to your project.
- Add a class that derives from [System.Configuration.Install.Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx) and has the [RunInstaller attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runinstallerattribute.aspx) applied.
- In its constructor create both a [ServiceProcessInstaller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceprocessinstaller(VS.80).aspx) and a [ServiceInstaller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller(VS.80).aspx) object.
- On the ServiceInstaller object you mark all the dependencies you want/need with the [ServicesDependedOn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.servicesdependedon(VS.80).aspx) property.
- Add these two installers to the [InstallersCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installercollection(VS.80).aspx) your installer inherited from System.Configuration.Install.Installer
- done.

edit: forgot to mention that you can use e.g. [Installutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95.aspx) to invoke the installer.

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class MyServiceInstaller : Installer
{
    public MyServiceInstaller()
    {
        using ( ServiceProcessInstaller procInstaller=new ServiceProcessInstaller() ) {
            procInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            using ( ServiceInstaller installer=new ServiceInstaller() ) {
                installer.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
                installer.ServiceName = "FooService";
                installer.DisplayName = "serves a lot of foo.";

                installer.ServicesDependedOn = new string [] { "CLIPBOOK" };
                this.Installers.Add(procInstaller);
                this.Installers.Add(installer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This can also be done via an elevated command prompt using the `sc` command. The syntax is:

```
sc config [service name] depend= <Dependencies(separated by / (forward slash))>
```

**Note**: There is a space *after* the equals sign, and there is *not* one before it.

**Warning**: `depend=` parameter will **overwrite** existing dependencies list, not append. So for example, if ServiceA already depends on ServiceB and ServiceC, if you run `depend= ServiceD`, ServiceA will now depend *only* on ServiceD.

### Examples

#### Dependency on one other service:

```
sc config ServiceA depend= ServiceB
```

Above means that ServiceA will not start until ServiceB has started. If you stop ServiceB, ServiceA will stop automatically.

#### Dependency on multiple other services:

```
sc config ServiceA depend= ServiceB/ServiceC/ServiceD
```

Above means that ServiceA will not start until ServiceB, ServiceC, and ServiceD have all started. If you stop any of ServiceB, ServiceC, or ServiceD, ServiceA will stop automatically.

#### To remove all dependencies:

```
sc config ServiceA depend= /
```

#### To list current dependencies:

```
sc qc ServiceA
```

Answer (score 1):

One method that's available is sc.exe.  It allows you to install and control services from a command prompt.  Here is an [older article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810435.aspx) covering it's use.  It does allow you to specify dependencies as well.

Take a look at the article for the **sc create** portion for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dynamic installer project on codeproject that I have found useful for services installation, in general.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio [Setup/Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t(VS.80).aspx) projects work for this.  They are not the best installer engine, but they work fine for simple scenarios.

Comment: where is a VS deployment project can you set a windows service's dependencies. He's not talking about prerequisites.