# run windows services in specific order

Tags: windows, service

Is it possible to change the order of windows services or run one service after another?

The reason i want this: I have IIS configuration located on a shared drive. And when i reboot server, it first run IIS (w3wp) service and couldn't start it. because at that point, shared network drive is not available. So i want to first finishing the network service to map all network drives and then run IIS service. so i don't need to restart IIS service every-time i reboot the server. is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a programming question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running Server 2008 / Vista / 7 you can set the IIS service for delayed start.

There are sort of two tiers: first all the "automatic" stuff, then the "automatic (delayed start)" stuff.

Answer (score 6):

By default, some Windows services are configured with "dependencies" to ensure that the prerequisite services are started first... so you can just add to them.

Here's [how to set dependencies with Registry edits](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193888) , [from the command-line](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sc.mspx?mfr=true) (`sc config ServiceName depend=servicetoDependOn`), and [from .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055942/installing-a-windows-service-with-dependencies).