# .NET Windows Services stopping order when the system shutdown

Tags: .net, windows-services

I'm creating a windows service that is supposed to send a request to a RESTFull service that is located on the same machine when the system shutdown. 
I want to make sure that my service OnStop() event will fire before the IIS service is stopped. 
Is there a way that I can control the order of services closure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft [documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685149(v=vs.85).aspx) this:

> To set the shutdown order of services manually, create a multistring
>   registry value that contains the service names in the order in which
>   they should be shut down and assign it to the Control key's
>   PreshutdownOrder value, as follows

There is little information about this on a sister site of stack exchange, so I provide the link instead of copying the content: https://serverfault.com/questions/34427/windows-service-dependencies

Comment: thanks a lot your answer helped me so much. is there a way to manage the order of services starting too?

Comment: yes, have a look at the last answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155913/run-windows-services-in-specific-order . And: using the search might help ;-)

Comment: i found that way already but was wondering whether there is a way to control it from registry just like the shutdown. Thanks again :)

Comment: The linked answer contains a link to Microsoft which tells you how to use registry to do this.