# my windows service starts before the sql server service

Tags: c#, service

I have a windows service written in c#, which when running connects to a sql server database.

When the service first starts it connects to the database to obtain various information for the service to run.

The service is set to automatically start if the server it is installed on is restarted.

If the service starts before the sql server service has started. My service when started obviously has an initial execption error when trying to connect to the database. 
To combat this issue, if the exception occurs I have added a short delay before try to connect to the database again, I continue this n amount of times until it connects

My question is, is there any alternative solutions to what I am doing already

thanks

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055942/installing-a-windows-service-with-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Make your service dependent on SQL Server, done using ‘sc’.

Using a poll, as you're doing right now is fie, and you'll still need it if your service starts after SQL Server because you can never be sure SQL Server has fully started then.